# Initial connections from HikariCP

Tags: hikaricp

My Spring Boot application connects with HikariCP to a Postgres database. I may be totally misreading something, so am reaching out for some pointers.

When the application starts, it opens 10 connections, and keeps them open by periodically sending a SQL statement to Postgres. Postgres is used only for a very limited part of my application, and definitely we don't need 10 open connections from application start-up. It would be better if I can get the connections can be established lazily, but wasn't able to find anything that allows that. So I've done the following in my YML:

```
...
  datasource:
    idleTimeout: 60000
    minimumIdle: 0
    maximumPoolSize: 5
```

Now I'm seeing 5 connections at start-up, better. Next hurdle was if the Postgres hostname cannot be resolved, the application won't start. For this, I've added:

```
initializationFailTimeout: -1
```

In the code, I have a configuration class like so:

```
@Configuration
public class PostgresConfig {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "...datasource")
    public DataSource postgresDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate postgresJdbcTemplate(DataSource postgresDataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(postgresDataSource);
    }
}
```

It feels like I missed something, such that by default, 10 connections are made and kept open, and if a connection can't be made at application start-up, an exception is thrown, and the application doesn't start. Is this the expected behavior?